# How does getExternalCacheDir() work on Android?

Tags: android, file, caching

From what I understand, we cache the frequently accessed objects in a memory segment that is more easily accessible than normal disk reads.

`getExternalCacheDir()`, as opposed to `getCacheDir()` points to the external filesystem - which seems to me as a normal `getExternalFilesDir()`.

How does Android optimize access to ExternalCacheDir? Is it something like the "swap" space on Linux?

Comment: Keep in mind that data you store using either of these methods is fully accessible to other applications which have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. You should assume that any data stored here can be read and modified (even potentially in a malicious manner) by other apps on the user's device. For more secure data storage, use getDir() or getCacheDir() instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getExternalCacheDir()` and `getExternalFilesDir()` are two different directories.

The difference is that the first one is intended only for temporary files or cache files that could be deleted by the system or the user (through the Settings corresponding button) to regain space.

The second one is intended for permanent files. Anyway, you have to take into account the considerations of the documentation regarding the directory returned by [`getExternalCacheDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29).

Comment: I basically want to know how does a cache on external filesystem provide faster access. This answer is not helping.

Comment: The term cache is used in those methods in its older not computer-related meaning, not representing that those directories provide faster access (as you are saying, it is the same filesystem with the same access times) but representing that those directories are somewhat hidden and useful to store files that the application could need.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here over "frequently accessed objects." You wouldn't use the getExternalCacheDir() directory to cache items already on the Android device. You would, however, using it to cache items transferred from a remote resource, such as a server. Example: a browser cache, where you may have the X most recently used files cached locally.

The cache directory is no different than any others file system directory in terms of write performance.