# Diff between getExternalCacheDir vs getExternalFilesDir in android

Tags: android, file, local-storage, android-file

I read the docs but I can't seem to figure out what the difference is. Is it something subtle that does not really matter? I want to create a cache of ten files. So when I went to use `getExternalFilesDir`, I noticed there is a `getExternalCacheDir`. So now I am confuse as to which one I should use (the name does not always tell the whole story). So can anyone put the difference in layman terms for me? thanks.

Comment: Similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731307/how-does-getexternalcachedir-work-on-android

Comment: N.B. [the security considerations associated with both of these methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()). "There is no security enforced with these files. For example, any application holding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE can write to these files." You should assume that any data stored using these methods can be read and modified (even potentially in a malicious manner) by other apps on the user's device. For secure data storage, use getDir() or getCacheDir() instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ExternalFilesDir is not a cache, it will save your files, and they will remain there until the app is removed or the files manually whereas the cachedir will empty when needed

Comment: The article @Gem_Ram points to says the opposite of your answer: `With the external cache storage Android doesn’t care at all. Even if the external storage is full, no cache files will be deleted.`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29 Partly right, the cache dir is not governed by your own app but devices running jellybean and later will clear cache if storage is full, files will be removed with your app and you should manage how much memory your app should take up in the cache dir

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newbie to Android but would like to help you with the below link. The below article explores all possible ways / methods to use under different scenarios. It helped me in improving my understanding and hope the same with you and others as well

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/how-to-correctly-store-app-specific-files-in-android/